# Double Scrollbars in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I cannot get x and y scrollbars to work in Tkinter with Python, although I have followed multiple examples:

1. [How to add 2 scrollbars with tkinter in python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533623/how-to-add-2-scrollbars-with-tkinter-in-python-3-4)
2. [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)
3. [How to make a proper double scrollbar frame in tkinter](https://lucasg.github.io/2015/07/21/How-to-make-a-proper-double-scrollbar-frame-in-Tkinter/)
4. [Vertical and Horizontal Scrollbars on Tkinter Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561030/vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars-on-tkinter-widget)
5. [Scrolling a Canvas widget horizontally and vertically](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/27784/scrolling-a-canvas-widget-horizontally-and-vertically)

The scrollbars appear, but do not activate when the window is smaller than the frame. How can I get this to work (see image below)?

[image: Problem 1]

Below is the minimal code that is producing my problem (Python 3.7)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

big_font = ("Arial", 50)

class DoubleScrollbarFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scroll_x = ttk.Scrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.HORIZONTAL,
                                      command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll_y = ttk.Scrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.VERTICAL,
                                      command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.scroll_x.set,
                           yscrollcommand = self.scroll_y.set)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),
                                  window = self.frame,
                                  anchor = 'nw')
        self.frame.bind('<Configure>',
                        self.set_scrollregion)
        self.sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)

        #Test
        self.test1 = tk.Label(self.frame,
                              text = 'Test 1',
                              font = big_font)
        self.test2 = tk.Label(self.frame,
                              text = 'Test 2',
                              font = big_font)
        self.test3 = tk.Label(self.frame,
                              text = 'Test 3',
                              font = big_font)

    def position_widgets(self,
                         **kwargs):
        self.test1.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'w')
        self.test2.grid(row = 1,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'w')
        self.test3.grid(row = 2,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'w')
        
        self.scroll_x.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 0,
                           sticky = 'ew')

        self.scroll_y.grid(row = 0,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 0,
                         sticky = 'nsew')
        
        self.frame.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'nsew')

        self.sizegrip.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'se')

    def set_scrollregion(self,
                         event):
        print('Frame Dimensions: {} x {}'.format(self.frame.winfo_width(),
                                                 self.frame.winfo_height()))
        print('Canvas Dimensions: {} x {}'.format(self.canvas.winfo_width(),
                                                  self.canvas.winfo_height()))
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))

class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.frame = DoubleScrollbarFrame(self)

    def position_widgets(self):
        self.frame.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'nsew')

    def exit(self):
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Create GUI
    root = MainApp()

    #Run program
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? For example, have you verified that the `scrollregion` is being updated to the correct values?

Comment: Please don't ask "bonus" questions - a good question asks about a single problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I removed the bonus question, added references to links I've reviewed, and added a printout in `set_scrollregion`. The method only outputs:

```Frame Dimensions: 193 x 243
Canvas Dimensions: 1 x 1```

and does not reprint when I resize the window.

Comment: You didn't answer the question of whether you've verified that `scrollregion` is being updated correctly.

Comment: @BryanOakley How do I verify `scrollregion` is updated correctly? Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: You can verify it is set correctly by looking at the result of `self.canvas.bbox('all')`, since you're using that value to configure `scrollregion`.

Comment: Very interesting. I never thought to print the output of that, but it makes perfect sense now that you mention it. Thank you!

Comment: @BryanOakley Can I borrow you for another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061101/scrollbars-for-matplotlib-figure-in-tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these lines of code inside `DoubleScrollbarFrame.position_widgets`:

```
self.frame.grid(row = 0,
                column = 0,
                sticky = 'nsew')
```

This removes control of the widget from the canvas and gives control to `grid`. It is no longer a canvas object, so `self.canvas.bbox("all")` is returning `(0, 0, 1, 1)`. If the scrollregion is set incorrectly, the scrollbars don't know how much to scroll.

The solution is simple: don't call `grid` on `self.frame`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! This works perfectly now. I read `Tkinter GUI Application Development Cookbook` by `Alejandro Rodas` and he states "...we did not call any geometry manager to draw the frame because the `create_window()` method does this for us." I had no idea that calling the geometry manager would pass control from the canvas to the grid! I wish someone had mentioned this in a book or tutorial!