# Scrollbars for Matplotlib Figure in Tkinter

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to get scrollbars to work in `Tkinter` for `matplotlib` figures. The scrollbars don't adjust to the width and height of the loaded image and I don't know how to troubleshoot this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Image**:

[image: Smiley]

**End Result:**

[image: Problem]

**Code:**

```
import os

from PIL import Image

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

import numpy as np

from functools import partial

class AutoScrollbar(ttk.Scrollbar):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

    def set(self,
            low,
            high):
        '''
        '''
        if float(low) <= 0.0 and float(high) >= 1.0:
            self.tk.call('grid',
                         'remove',
                         self)
        else:
            self.grid()
        ttk.Scrollbar.set(self,
                          low,
                          high)

class DoubleScrollbarFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scroll_x = AutoScrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scroll_y = AutoScrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.VERTICAL)
        self.sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)
        
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.scroll_x.set,
                           yscrollcommand = self.scroll_y.set)
        self.scroll_x.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll_y.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),
                                  window = self.frame,
                                  anchor = 'nw')
        
        self.frame.bind('<Configure>',
                        self.set_scrollregion)

    def position_widgets(self,
                         **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.scroll_x.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 0,
                           sticky = 'ew')

        self.scroll_y.grid(row = 0,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 0,
                         sticky = 'nsew')

        self.sizegrip.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'se')

        #NOTE: Do not use geometry manager with `self.frame`. This will
        # pass control from the canvas to grid and the canvas will then
        # no longer know how much to grow.
        
    def set_scrollregion(self,
                         event):
        '''
        '''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))

class Graph(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 axis_off = True,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent
        self.axis_off = axis_off

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.graph_container = DoubleScrollbarFrame(self)
        
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(top = 1,
                                    right = 1,
                                    left= 0,
                                    bottom = 0,
                                    wspace = 0,
                                    hspace = 0)
            
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)

        if self.axis_off:
            self.axis.set_axis_off()

        self.mpl_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure,
                                            self.graph_container.frame)

        self.toolbar_frame = ttk.Frame(self)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.mpl_canvas,
                                            self.toolbar_frame)
        
    def position_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar_frame.grid(row = 1,
                                column = 0,
                                sticky = 'sew')

        self.mpl_canvas.draw()
        self.mpl_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0,
                                             column = 0,
                                             sticky = 'nsew')

        self.graph_container.grid(row = 0,
                                  column = 0,
                                  sticky = 'nsew')

    def load_image(self,
                   path):
        '''
        '''
        self.mpl_canvas.flush_events()
        self.axis.clear()
        
        self.image = Image.open(path)

        #NOTE: Dots per inch (dpi) in matplotlib should be used for
        # printing to paper media only. dpi is set at the time of
        # printing/scanning. Computer screen resolution is fixed by
        # the screen hardware and given in pixels per inch (ppi).
        # An image scanned at higher dpi will appear crisper on a
        # computer screen because of the difference in halftone/
        # dithering at each pixel, but the total size and number of
        # pixels in the image will be the same.
        # Matplotlib use 72 pixels per inch (ppi) for its figures by
        # default, and this cannot be changed. Thus, if you increase
        # dots per inch (dpi), the figure will appear bigger when
        # printed to screen (i.e. on the computer monitor) because
        # it will use more pixels to represent the same features.
        # When printed to paper media, however, the image will be
        # the same size regardless of dpi, but have finer halftoning/
        # dithering for an improved appearance.
        # Matplotlib sets sizes in terms of inches, so the scan dpi
        # must be known in order to get the physical size of the
        # image.
        if self.image.info.get('dpi'):
            self.scan_dpi, _ = self.image.info['dpi']
        else:
            self.scan_dpi = 100
        self.w_pel, self.h_pel = self.image.size

        self.graph_w_in = self.w_pel / self.scan_dpi
        self.graph_h_in = self.h_pel / self.scan_dpi
        self.graph_aspect_ratio = self.graph_h_in / self.graph_w_in

        self.zoom = 1
        
        self.figure.set_size_inches(self.graph_w_in * self.zoom,
                                    self.graph_h_in * self.zoom)
        
        self.image = np.array(self.image)
        
        self.axis.imshow(self.image)

        self.mpl_canvas.draw()

class FileBrowser(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 path_type = 'file',
                 label_text = '',
                 file_types = (('*','All File Types...'),),
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent
        self.path_type = path_type
        self.label_text = label_text
        self.file_types = file_types
        
        super().__init__(parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.label = tk.Label(self.parent,
                              text = self.label_text)

        self.path_entry = tk.Entry(self.parent,
                                   width = 50)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self.parent,
                                 text = 'Browse...',
                                 command = partial(self.open_file_dialog,
                                                   self.path_type,
                                                   self.file_types))

    def position_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        opts = {'padx': (5,5),
                'pady': (5,5)}
        
        self.label.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'e',
                        **opts)
        self.path_entry.grid(row = 0,
                             column = 1,
                             sticky = 'w',
                             **opts)
        self.button.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 2,
                         sticky = 'w',
                         **opts)

    def open_file_dialog(self,
                         path_type,
                         file_types):
        '''
        '''
        init_dir = os.getcwd()

        if path_type == 'file':
             self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = init_dir,
                                                    title = 'Select file...',
                                                    filetypes = file_types)
        elif path_type == 'directory':
            self.path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = init_dir,
                                                title = 'Select directory...')

        self.path_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.path_entry.insert(0,self.path)

    def get_path(self):
        '''
        '''
        return self.path_entry.get()

class Loader(ttk.Frame):
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.input_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self,
                                                text = 'Input')
        self.output_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self,
                                                 text = 'Output')
        
        self.create_file_browser(self.input_label_frame)
        self.create_ok_button(self.input_label_frame)

        self.create_output_window(self.output_label_frame)

    def create_file_browser(self,
                            label_frame):
        '''
        '''
        self.browser_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(label_frame,
                                            text = 'Select File')
        self.file_browser = FileBrowser(self.browser_frame,
                                        path_type = 'file',
                                        label_text = 'File:',
                                        file_types = (('*.tif', 'TIF'),
                                                      ('*.png', 'PNG'),))

    def create_ok_button(self,
                         label_frame):
        '''
        '''
        self.input_ok_button = ttk.Button(label_frame,
                                          text = 'OK',
                                          command = self.calibrate)

    def calibrate(self):
        '''
        '''
        path = self.file_browser.get_path()

        if path == '':
            messagebox.showerror(title = 'No File Selected',
                                 message = 'No file chosen. Please select file.')
            return

        _, ext = os.path.splitext(path)

        if ext.lower() not in ('.tif', '.png'):
            messagebox.showerror(title = 'File Is Not \"*.tif\" or \"*.png\"',
                                 message = 'File must be a \"*.tif\" or \"*.png\" image file. Please reselect file and try again.')

        img = plt.imread(path)

        self.graph.load_image(path)
        
    def create_output_window(self,
                             label_frame):
        '''
        '''
        self.output_frame = ttk.Frame(label_frame)
        self.graph = Graph(self.output_frame)

    def position_widgets(self,
                         **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        #OK Button
        self.input_ok_button.grid(row = 4,
                                  column = 0,
                                  sticky = 'e')
        
        #Frames
        self.input_label_frame.grid(row = 0,
                                    column = 0,
                                    sticky = 'nsew')
        
        self.browser_frame.grid(row = 1,
                                column = 0,
                                sticky = 'nw')

        self.file_browser.grid(row = 0,
                               column = 0,
                               sticky = 'nsew')

        self.output_label_frame.grid(row = 0,
                                     column = 1,
                                     sticky = 'nw')

        self.graph.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'nsew')

        self.output_frame.grid(row = 0,
                               column = 0,
                               sticky = 'nsew')


class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,
                 title,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self._title = title

        super().__init__(*args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Set window title
        self.title(self._title)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.loader = Loader(self)

    def position_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.loader.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 0,
                         sticky = 'nsew')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Create GUI
    root = MainApp('MainApp')

    #Run program
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matplotlib` figures are canvases. Therfore, its container frame won't resize to it, and `bbox("all")` won't work. Instead, we have to update the `matplotlib` `canvas` size to match the `figure` size and the toplevel `canvas` `scrollregion` to the `figure` size.

Here is the working output.

**Working Output**

[image: Answer]

Here is the working code.

**Code**

```
import os

from PIL import Image

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

import numpy as np

from functools import partial

#Matplotlib Default DPI
DEFAULT_DPI = 100

#Matplotlib Default PPI
DEFAULT_PPI = 72

class AutoScrollbar(ttk.Scrollbar):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

    def set(self,
            low,
            high):
        '''
        '''
        if float(low) <= 0.0 and float(high) >= 1.0:
            self.tk.call('grid',
                         'remove',
                         self)
        else:
            self.grid()
        ttk.Scrollbar.set(self,
                          low,
                          high)

class DoubleScrollbarFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scroll_x = AutoScrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scroll_y = AutoScrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.VERTICAL)
        self.sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)
        
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.scroll_x.set,
                           yscrollcommand = self.scroll_y.set)
        self.scroll_x.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll_y.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),
                                  window = self.frame,
                                  anchor = 'nw')
        
        self.frame.bind('<Configure>',
                        self.set_scrollregion)

    def position_widgets(self,
                         **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.scroll_x.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 0,
                           sticky = 'ew')

        self.scroll_y.grid(row = 0,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 0,
                         sticky = 'nsew')

        self.sizegrip.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'se')

        #NOTE: Do not use geometry manager with `self.frame`. This will
        # pass control from the canvas to grid and the canvas will then
        # no longer know how much to grow.
        
    def set_scrollregion(self,
                         event):
        '''
        '''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))

class Graph(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 axis_off = True,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent
        self.axis_off = axis_off

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(top = 1,
                                    right = 1,
                                    left= 0,
                                    bottom = 0,
                                    wspace = 0,
                                    hspace = 0)
            
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)

        if self.axis_off:
            self.axis.set_axis_off()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.canvas)

        self.mpl_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure,
                                            self.frame)

        self.mpl_canvas.draw()

        self.scroll_x = AutoScrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.HORIZONTAL)
        self.scroll_y = AutoScrollbar(self,
                                      orient = tk.VERTICAL)
        self.sizegrip = ttk.Sizegrip(self)
        
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand = self.scroll_x.set,
                           yscrollcommand = self.scroll_y.set)
        self.scroll_x.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll_y.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        
        self.cwid = self.canvas.create_window((0,0),
                                              window = self.frame,
                                              anchor = 'nw')

        self.frame.bind('<Configure>',
                        self.set_scrollregion)

        self.toolbar_frame = ttk.Frame(self)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.mpl_canvas,
                                            self.toolbar_frame)

    def set_scrollregion(self,
                         event):
        '''
        '''
        w, h = self.figure.get_size_inches()
        w = int(w * DEFAULT_DPI)
        h = int(h * DEFAULT_DPI)
        scrollregion = (0,0,w,h)
        
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = scrollregion)
        
    def position_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.scroll_x.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 0,
                           sticky = 'ew')

        self.scroll_y.grid(row = 0,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 0,
                         sticky = 'nsew')

        self.mpl_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 0,
                                             column = 0,
                                             sticky = 'nsew')

        self.sizegrip.grid(row = 1,
                           column = 1,
                           sticky = 'se')

        #NOTE: Do not use geometry manager with `self.frame`. This will
        # pass control from the canvas to grid and the canvas will then
        # no longer know how much to grow.

        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar_frame.grid(row = 2,
                                column = 0,
                                sticky = 'sew')

    def load_image(self,
                   path):
        '''
        '''
        self.mpl_canvas.flush_events()
        self.axis.clear()
        
        self.image = Image.open(path)

        #NOTE: Dots per inch (dpi) in matplotlib should be used for
        # printing to paper media only. dpi is set at the time of
        # printing/scanning. Computer screen resolution is fixed by
        # the screen hardware and given in pixels per inch (ppi).
        # An image scanned at higher dpi will appear crisper on a
        # computer screen because of the difference in halftone/
        # dithering at each pixel, but the total size and number of
        # pixels in the image will be the same.
        # Matplotlib use 72 pixels per inch (ppi) for its figures by
        # default, and this cannot be changed. Thus, if you increase
        # dots per inch (dpi), the figure will appear bigger when
        # printed to screen (i.e. on the computer monitor) because
        # it will use more pixels to represent the same features.
        # When printed to paper media, however, the image will be
        # the same size regardless of dpi, but have finer halftoning/
        # dithering for an improved appearance.
        # Matplotlib sets sizes in terms of inches, so the scan dpi
        # must be known in order to get the physical size of the
        # image.
        if self.image.info.get('dpi'):
            self.scan_dpi, _ = self.image.info['dpi']
        else:
            self.scan_dpi = DEFAULT_DPI # matplotlib default
            
        self.w_pel, self.h_pel = self.image.size

        self.graph_w_in = self.w_pel / self.scan_dpi
        self.graph_h_in = self.h_pel / self.scan_dpi        
        
        self.figure.set_size_inches(self.graph_w_in,
                                    self.graph_h_in)
        
        self.image = np.array(self.image)
        
        self.axis.imshow(self.image)

        self.mpl_canvas.get_tk_widget().configure(
            width = self.graph_w_in * DEFAULT_DPI,
            height = self.graph_h_in * DEFAULT_DPI)
        
        self.mpl_canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.update()

class FileBrowser(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 path_type = 'file',
                 label_text = '',
                 file_types = (('*','All File Types...'),),
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent
        self.path_type = path_type
        self.label_text = label_text
        self.file_types = file_types
        
        super().__init__(parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.label = tk.Label(self.parent,
                              text = self.label_text)

        self.path_entry = tk.Entry(self.parent,
                                   width = 50)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self.parent,
                                 text = 'Browse...',
                                 command = partial(self.open_file_dialog,
                                                   self.path_type,
                                                   self.file_types))

    def position_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        opts = {'padx': (5,5),
                'pady': (5,5)}
        
        self.label.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'e',
                        **opts)
        self.path_entry.grid(row = 0,
                             column = 1,
                             sticky = 'w',
                             **opts)
        self.button.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 2,
                         sticky = 'w',
                         **opts)

    def open_file_dialog(self,
                         path_type,
                         file_types):
        '''
        '''
        init_dir = os.getcwd()

        if path_type == 'file':
             self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = init_dir,
                                                    title = 'Select file...',
                                                    filetypes = file_types)
        elif path_type == 'directory':
            self.path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = init_dir,
                                                title = 'Select directory...')

        self.path_entry.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.path_entry.insert(0,self.path)

    def get_path(self):
        '''
        '''
        return self.path_entry.get()

class Loader(ttk.Frame):
    '''
    '''
    def __init__(self,
                 parent,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self.parent = parent

        super().__init__(self.parent,
                         *args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.input_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self,
                                                text = 'Input')
        self.output_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self,
                                                 text = 'Output')
        
        self.create_file_browser(self.input_label_frame)
        self.create_ok_button(self.input_label_frame)

        self.create_output_window(self.output_label_frame)

    def create_file_browser(self,
                            label_frame):
        '''
        '''
        self.browser_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(label_frame,
                                            text = 'Select File')
        self.file_browser = FileBrowser(self.browser_frame,
                                        path_type = 'file',
                                        label_text = 'File:',
                                        file_types = (('*.tif', 'TIF'),
                                                      ('*.png', 'PNG'),))

    def create_ok_button(self,
                         label_frame):
        '''
        '''
        self.input_ok_button = ttk.Button(label_frame,
                                          text = 'OK',
                                          command = self.calibrate)

    def calibrate(self):
        '''
        '''
        path = self.file_browser.get_path()

        if path == '':
            messagebox.showerror(title = 'No File Selected',
                                 message = 'No file chosen. Please select file.')
            return

        _, ext = os.path.splitext(path)

        if ext.lower() not in ('.tif', '.png'):
            messagebox.showerror(title = 'File Is Not \"*.tif\" or \"*.png\"',
                                 message = 'File must be a \"*.tif\" or \"*.png\" image file. Please reselect file and try again.')

        img = plt.imread(path)

        self.graph.load_image(path)
        
    def create_output_window(self,
                             label_frame):
        '''
        '''
        self.output_frame = ttk.Frame(label_frame)
        self.graph = Graph(self.output_frame)

    def position_widgets(self,
                         **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        #OK Button
        self.input_ok_button.grid(row = 4,
                                  column = 0,
                                  sticky = 'e')
        
        #Frames
        self.input_label_frame.grid(row = 0,
                                    column = 0,
                                    sticky = 'nsew')
        
        self.browser_frame.grid(row = 1,
                                column = 0,
                                sticky = 'nw')

        self.file_browser.grid(row = 0,
                               column = 0,
                               sticky = 'nsew')

        self.output_label_frame.grid(row = 0,
                                     column = 1,
                                     sticky = 'nw')

        self.graph.grid(row = 0,
                        column = 0,
                        sticky = 'nsew')

        self.output_frame.grid(row = 0,
                               column = 0,
                               sticky = 'nsew')


class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,
                 title,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self._title = title

        super().__init__(*args,
                         **kwargs)

        #Set widgets to fill main window such that they are
        #all the same size
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #Set window title
        self.title(self._title)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.position_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.loader = Loader(self)

    def position_widgets(self):
        '''
        '''
        self.loader.grid(row = 0,
                         column = 0,
                         sticky = 'nsew')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #Create GUI
    root = MainApp('MainApp')

    #Run program
    root.mainloop()
```