# Tkinter scrollbar not moving

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll

I have a bunch of checkboxes instantiated in Tkinter, and I would like to scroll through the window because all of them cannot be fit in one frame. I see the scrollbar, but there is no effect on using it, and the window stays stationary. How can I fix it? This is my code -

```
root = Tk()
scroll = Scrollbar(root) 
scroll.pack(fill=Y,side=RIGHT)

l = []
for checkBoxName in all_files:
    var = IntVar()
    c = Checkbutton(root, text=checkBoxName, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    c.pack()
    l.append(var)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searches from the internet, I found what you need.

**Note: Everything below is not mine, all the source I will put below.**

---

So, this is what you need:

```
# Create A Main frame
main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Create Frame for X Scrollbar
sec = Frame(main_frame)
sec.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)

# Create A Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Add A Scrollbars to Canvas
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.config(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox(ALL)))

# Create Another Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

# Add that New Frame a Window In The Canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
```

and the full code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

all_files = [str(i) for i in range(100)]  # your list

root = Tk()

# Create A Main frame
main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Create Frame for X Scrollbar
sec = Frame(main_frame)
sec.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)

# Create A Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Add A Scrollbars to Canvas
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.config(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox(ALL)))

# Create Another Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

# Add that New Frame a Window In The Canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

#==========
l = []
for checkBoxName in all_files:
    var = IntVar()
    c = Checkbutton(second_frame, text=checkBoxName, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    c.pack()
    l.append(var)
#==========

root.mainloop()
```

There is also an another shorter way:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import *

all_files = [str(i) for i in range(100)]  # your list

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(width="500",height="500")
frame.pack()
swin = ScrolledWindow(frame, width=500, height=500)
swin.pack()
win = swin.window

#==========
l = []
for checkBoxName in all_files:
    var = IntVar()
    c = Checkbutton(win, text=checkBoxName, variable=var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    c.pack()
    l.append(var)
#==========

root.mainloop()
```

---

To be honest, I'm not too good at tkinter, and I just have a little experience about it, so I don't really understand how they could make this code.

**Sources**:

1. [First Way](https://splunktool.com/python-tkinter-scrollbar-for-entire-window)
2. [Video Tutorial (1st way)](https://youtu.be/0WafQCaok6g)
3. [Another Way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1845422/17990633)